# How to toggle the external screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display

I have a laptop connected to an external monitor. Need to do a presentation where I have Powerpoint open on one screen and Excel on another screen and toggle the external screen

So: the laptop screen should always show Excel but the external screen should show either PP or Excel.
I put display into extended mode, put PP on a second screen. so far so good. But then I need to switch external screen to Excel. If I change to Duplicate mode, my PP moves to the main screen and I cannot switch easily back.

Is there a way to quickly and easy switch only the external monitor between main and extended screens?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on Extended Mode always. Based on your requirement, you can manually drag the respective Application (in your case Excel/PowerPoint) to whichever screen you want.

You also can tweak the PowerPoint Slide Show setting to define which monitor to use and also whether to use Presenter View or not (refer screenshot)

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: The fist option is not what I need. Excel must always stay on the first screen whether it is also shown on the second screen or not.  I will try the second option tonight and see if it works.

Comment: kamleshrao,  I have tried your suggestion. It does not work. As soon as I switch back to duplicate mode the PP move to the first screen and stays there, ignoring that it is told to use the second screen, Need to stop the slide show and start it again to make it appear at a second screen